# Liste aller Wörter, die in den jeweiligen Duden-Ausgaben neu aufgenommen wurden

Tags: resource, vocabulary, dictionary, duden

Ich bin auf der Suche nach einer Liste aller Wörter, die in den jeweiligen Ausgaben des Duden-Wörterbuchs **neu aufgenommen** wurden. Mich interessieren die Wörter der letzten 40 bis 50 Jahre. Sie sollten nach Jahrgang/Auflage gruppiert sein.

Eine Übersicht der bisher (2011) erschienenen Ausgaben ist übrigens [hier](http://www.duden.de/ueber_duden/auflagengeschichte) zu finden.

Gibt es eine derartige Liste im Internet?

**Update**

Da sich anscheinend keine vollständige Liste findet lässt, habe ich mal einen Community-Wiki-Beitrag erstellt, bei dem jeder mitarbeiten kann, wenn sie oder er Lust dazu hat. Ich habe mal etwas, was ich über die letzte Ausgabe von 2009 gefunden habe, eingefügt.

---

P.S.: Bonuspunkte für die Liste der Wörter, die **entfernt** wurden und evtl. eine Erklärung, wie die Kriterien lauten für eine Aufnahme und wie der Ablauf dafür ist.

Comment: Benutzt der Duden denn keine Versionsverwaltung? ;)

Comment: Not exactly what's requested but related: http://www.duden.de/presse/unsere-woerter-des-jahrzehnts.

Answer (score 3):

### 25. Ausgabe (2009)

Mehr als 5000 neu aufgenommene Wörter, insgesamt rund 135.000 Stichwörter.

*Einige Beispiele:*

Abwrackprämie, After-Show-Party, Angsthäsin, armutsgefährdet, aufstarten (schweiz.), Aufstocker, Aufstockerin, ausschnapsen, austillen, Babyblues, Bad Bank, Barfußpfad, Bedienungstheke, Best-of, B-Führerschein, Bioethikkommission, Blaufahrer, Blaufahrerin (schweiz.), Blogosphäre, Blu-ray®, Blutdiamant, Börsenzocker, Buschfunk, Campusmaut, Cem, Chardonnay, Chorizo, Citymaut, Clutch, Crema, Datenklau, DAU, Dopingarzt, Dopingärztin, Effizienzklasse, Ehrenmord, Einbürgerungstest, Einkaufsnacht, einpreisen, Energiepass, entpacken, Ersti, euroskeptisch, Exzellenzcluster, Fanmeile, Featurette, fehlernähren, Feinstaubplakette, Fernbeziehung, Flatrateparty, Formatfernsehen, Frauenversteher, fremdschämen, Gassenarbeit (schweiz.), Gefährder, Gefährderin, Gelotologie, Gesundheitsfonds, Gigaliner, Handy-TV, Heizpilz, Herdprämie, hirnen (schweiz.), Hüftgold, Hybridauto, Industriekletterer, Industriekletterin, Inselbegabte, Integrationsgipfel, internetaffin, Internetfernsehen, It-Girl, Kangchendzönga, Klimakiller, Komasaufen, Konjunkturpaket, Kreditklemme, Kuschelkurs, Lebensmensch (österr.), Löli (schweiz.), Luxese, Mehrgenerationenhaus, Mentoring, Nacktscanner, Nickname, niedrigschwellig, No-go-Area, Ökopunkt (österr.), Onlinedurchsuchung, Partikelfilter, Phrasenschwein, Poolnudel, Prekariat, Probeführerschein, Produktpiraterie, Public Viewing, Raucherkneipe, Regenbogenfamilie, Rettungsschirm S: Sashimi, Schadstoffplakette, Schlüsselkraft, Schockfoto, Schümlikaffee, Seitenblickegesellschaft (österr.), Skimming, slammen, Snowciety (österr.), snowkiten, Sofortrente, Sommermärchen, Sprengstoffweste, Stehroller, Steueridentifikationsnummer, Stockbrot, Tankini, twittern, Umweltplakette, Umweltzone, urcool, Vätermonat, verjankern (österr.), verzocken, Vogelschlag, vorglühen (vorab Alkohol trinken), Vorratsdatenspeicherung, Web 2.0, Weltklimarat, Wiki, Wutrede, Zwergplanet

*Quellen: [welt.de/kultur](http://www.welt.de/kultur/article4155107/Die-wichtigsten-neuen-Woerter-im-aktuellen-Duden.html), [duden.de](http://www.duden.de/ueber_duden/auflagengeschichte)*

---

### 24. Ausgabe (2006)

Mehr als 3500 neu aufgenommene Wörter, insgesamt rund 130.000 Stichwörter

*Einige Beispiele:*

Auflaufkinder, austicken, Best Ager, Blog, Brötchentaste, Castingshow, Champagnerdusche, Designer-Outlet,  Drop-down-Menü, Dudelfunk, durchregieren, Eheschein, Ein-Euro-Job, Einwahlpunkt, E-Learning, Elterngeld, E-Pass, ergebnisoffen, EUFOR, Eventgastronomie, Fallmanager, Feinstaubbelastung, flashen, fluffig, Funktionskleidung, Gender-Mainstreaming, Gammelfleisch, Goleo VI, Guantánamo, Guthabenkarte, H5N1-Virus, Hacklerregelung (österr.), handyfrei, Hassprediger, HDTV, Heuschreckenkapitalismus, Holocaustmahnmal, Internetauktion, Internettelefonie, jedefrau, Jobcenter, Karrierenetzwerk, Knopflochchirurgie, Kompetenzteam, Kopfpauschale, Kundenkarte, Lebensmittelpunkt, Lifestylemagazin, Memorystick, Nanotechnik, Open-Source-Software, Palliativmedizin, Pancetta, Phishing, Plasmafernseher, podcasten, Pull-down-Menü, Publikumsjoker, Roibuschtee, Rucksackbomber, Saalwette, Scoubidou, Shiitake, Stallpflicht, Sudoku, talentfrei, Tapa, Telenovela, Turbokapitalismus, USB-Stick, vermüllen, voipen, Weblog, webweit, wegklicken, Widescreen, Wohlfühlfaktor, Zuckerfest

*Quellen: [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duden#24._Auflage_.282006.29), [rp-online.de](http://www.rp-online.de/beruf/bildung/3000-neue-Woerter-im-Duden_bid_17207.html)*

---

### 23. Ausgabe (2004)

Rund 5000 neu aufgenommene Wörter, insgesamt rund 125.000 Stichwörter.

*Einige Beispiele:*

Billigflieger, Dosenpfand, Fotohandy, googeln, Ich-AG, Kuckuckskind, Minijob, Nanotechnologie, Osterweiterung, Quotenbringer, Sars, Teuro, UNO-Waffeninspektor, Webdesign, Zentralabitur

*Quelle: [rp-online.de](http://www.rp-online.de/beruf/bildung/Der-neue-Duden-googelt_aid_59550.html), [perlentaucher.de](http://www.perlentaucher.de/buch/18654.html)*